# $merge with unique index on output collection not working

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am using $merge to inserting data from one collection to another

```
 db.outputcoll.createIndex( { newcoll: 1 }, { unique: true } )

 db.testcoll
        .aggregate([
          { "$project": {"_id": 0 } },
          {
            $addFields: {
              newcoll: '$user_id',
              created_at: new Date(),
              updated_at: new Date(),
            },
          },
          { $merge: { into: 'outputcoll', on: "newcoll", whenMatched: "keepExisting", whenNotMatched: "insert" } }
        ])
```

When testcoll has duplicate user_id then I am getting error

```
MongoError: E11000 duplicate key error collection: outputcoll index: newcoll_1 dup key: { newcoll: 5 }
```

Comment: if you have a unique index on a field in a collection, you can have the same value on that field in the same collection.Here you cant have 2 documents with same value on `newcoll` (if you try to do it you get this error), Thats why it is called unique, 1 key - 1 doc max

Comment: @Takis_ I need only one value that's why I choose keepExisting

Comment: Looks like synchronization problem, like both see that doesn't exist, try to insert, and the second complains(because the first one already inserted it). If possible maybe not allow duplicate values? Maybe wait better answers. But looks like that.

Comment: if you cant find solution maybe try to do the same with `update/upsert` pipeline.